# ExtJS select an item based on matching attributes

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to select an item in an `Ext.tree.Panel` based on an item with the same attribute in an `Ext.grid.Panel'`. Something like: `tree_dir.getSelectionModel().select(grid_file.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].id);`

Any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To select node in tree, there is `selectPath` method provided. You can find node by id for example by calling `getNodeById` on store.

Example usage:

```
var selectNodeById = function(id) {
    var path = [];

    for (var n = store.getNodeById(id); n; n = n.parentNode) {
        path.unshift(n.get('id'));
    }
    tree.selectPath('/' + path.join('/'), 'id');
};
```